# Node.js simple script memory leaking

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

Here is a simple code

```
var fn = function () {
    return null;
}

setInterval(fn, 100);

setInterval(function () {
    global.gc();
    console.log(process.memoryUsage().rss);
}, 1000);
```

Runnig

node --expose-gc /tmp/test.js

Result:

```
10330112
10596352
10596352
10596352
10932224
10932224
10932224
... several minutes 
11198464
11198464
11198464
```

Why memory is increasing?

Comment: Which node.js version do you have? I ran your script on `v0.10.31` for about 20 minutes and saw no leaks. http://pastebin.com/hwJHWZtg

Comment: Ubuntu 13, node v0.10.25 I've tried on another one: Debian 3.2 node v0.10.15 and got the same, just later.